# Show content in a Powerpoint slide incrementally

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, presentations, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I have seen Powerpoint presentations where content showed up slide incrementally. i.e. Suppose there is 20 lines of content on the slide. However, when you see the slide for first time, you only see 5 lines. Then, the presenter presses a button, and you see next 5 lines, so on, until you eventually see all the lines in the slide.

What is the name of this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [animations](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Apply-an-animation-effect-to-text-or-objects-df509fcc-9088-476d-ba83-ece59b6005a0). These features are located on the `Animation` tab. Select the text and choose your animation.

[image]

Then you can adjust the settings in the toolbar in the `Timing` group.

[image]